# Kendo grid export to excel and hide few column in excel

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, export-to-excel, asp.net-mvc-5

In .Net MVC 5 angular js, How to Export kendo grid data to excel with few column. i dont want to export all columns which are shown in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Hope below links will help you. http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/export-checked-columns-only

http://www.telerik.com/forums/export-to-grid-hide-columns